# JFrame doesn't display components

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have problem with displaying components on my JFrame. I'm closing my current window and opening new one and want to display jLabel on it but nothing is happening. Code is below :

```
               Frame[] nF = DBChooser.getFrames(); 

                nF[0].setVisible(false);
                JFrame windoow = new JFrame("Processing");                       
                JPanel pan = new JPanel(); 
                windoow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));  
                pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));                  

                JLabel textLabel = new JLabel ("Processing...");   
                textLabel.setLayout(null);
                pan.setLayout(null);
                windoow.setLayout(null);                   
                pan.add(textLabel);
                pan.revalidate();
                pan.repaint();                 
                windoow.getContentPane().add(pan); 
                windoow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                    
                windoow.pack();                  
                windoow.setVisible(true);
```

I appreciate any help

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and ..

Comment: .. if resizable, with more width and height.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you set a null layout to window and panel without specifying any width, lenght or position, either use some `LayoutManager` or set these properties (eg. bounds). A null LayoutManager means that you need to set everything yourself, because there is nothing (no LayoutManager) that would place your elements automatically. This example uses a BorderLayout, which creates a nice effect:

[image]

the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame windoow = new JFrame("Processing");
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        windoow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));

        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Processing...");
        textLabel.setLayout(null);
        pan.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        windoow.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pan.add(textLabel);
        pan.revalidate();
        pan.repaint();
        windoow.getContentPane().add(pan);
        windoow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        windoow.pack();
        windoow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same, label isn't displaying

Comment: @johansonik How can it be not displayed when i have run the same code, and I've post you the image of window with the message?

Comment: @johansonik Are you using exactly this code that I've posted in my answer?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Comment: @johansonik, please copy&paste this single class above and run it - it will show the exact window as the one I've posted.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need so many `setLayout(null);` ? I remove them and it worked

```
public class DBChooser extends Frame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Frame[] nF = DBChooser.getFrames();
//      nF[0].setVisible(false);
        JFrame windoow = new JFrame("Processing");
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        windoow.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        pan.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        JLabel textLabel = new JLabel("Processing...");
//      textLabel.setLayout(null);
//      pan.setLayout(null);
//      windoow.setLayout(null);                   
        pan.add(textLabel);
        pan.revalidate();
        pan.repaint();
        windoow.getContentPane().add(pan);
        windoow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        windoow.pack();
        windoow.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't help, label isn't displaying

Comment: It works fine in my pc. Maybe you need to post more code here

Comment: What is `nF[0].setVisible(false);`? Are you sure your code can compile without commenting this ?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it can. This nF[0] is the main window (frame) of my program but it works fine.

Comment: please post the code that can compile by adding main function